# Need Post Article In wordpress but some contain display HTML format using plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

for developing blog site post article well but inside article post some post display in html format like as below

```
Theme Name: Twenty Eleven Child Theme
  Theme URI: http://example.com
  Author: you!
  Author URI: http://example.com/
  Description:  Child theme based on Twenty Eleven.
  Template: twentyeleven
  Version: 1.0
  Tags: your tags (optional)
```

so above contain would be display in front-end post of article in html format so didn't find for that plugin you have any idea then share to me.....

Comment: Could you elaborate more upon what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: eg.check sample website http://www.codingcage.com/2015/01/user-registration-and-login-script-using-php-mysql.html    in this article some contain display in message style and example would be display in box inside html format  like show inside this article dbconnect.php so i need how to do that html format